# Why the characters in a string is not counted?

Tags: java

I made a program to count the number of alphanumeric characters in a string i failed one test case where for any input in the form of "as(Any no of spaces in the middle)der" is printing 3 instead of 5.I am not knowing the reason why?

Below is my SourceCode

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class CharCount
{ 
 static int Count=0;
 static int charcount()
{  
   System.out.println("Enter the String");

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String userString=sc.next();
    char ch[]=userString.toCharArray();


    for(int i=0;i<ch.length;)
    {
     if(ch[i]>=65&&ch[i]<=122||ch[i]==32)
     {
       if(ch[i]==32)
       {
          i++;
       }
       else
       {
        Count++;
        i++;
       }
     }

    else
    {
      System.out.println("Enter only alphabetical characters");
      break;
    }
   }
  System.out.println("Alphabetical characters till date is");
  return Count;
}

public static void main(String s[])
 { 
   charcount();

 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem lies in this statement:

```
String userString=sc.next();
```

It will only read the first word when you have spaces in the input. You need

```
String userString=sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen How ?I could not analyse.In terms of ?can you give me an example or a hint.

Comment: @JalajChawla What do you mean by `In terms of ?` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sir I mean what  are other problems.Are you pointing to time and space complexity.